# vagrant primary box defined but commands still run against all boxes

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to set my "dev" VM as primary so most commands such as `vagrant up`, `vagrant halt`, etc operate on the "dev" VM and ignore the "stage" VM unless the "stage" VM name is explicitly listed on the command line. Here's my Vagrantfile, but when I run `vagrant up` both VMs are brought up instead of just "dev".

```
# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

def box_setup(config, ip, playbook, inventory)
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = playbook
    ansible.inventory_path = inventory
    # ansible.verbose = "vvv"
  end
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # common settings shared by all vagrant boxes for this project
  config.vm.box = "debian-7-amd64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xymcvez85i29lym/vagrant-debian-wheezy64.box"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  # development box intended for ongoing development
  config.vm.define "dev", primary: true do |dev|
    box_setup dev, \
      "10.9.8.30", "deploy/playbook_dev.yml", "deploy/hosts/vagrant_dev.yml"
  end
  # stage box intended for configuration closely matching production
  config.vm.define "stage" do |stage|
    box_setup stage, \
      "10.9.8.31", "deploy/playbook_full_stack.yml", "deploy/hosts/vagrant_stage.yml"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary flag seems to only work for `vagrant ssh` for me.

In the past I have used the following method to hack around the issue.

```
# stage box intended for configuration closely matching production
if ARGV[1] == 'stage'
    config.vm.define "stage" do |stage|
        box_setup stage, \
        "10.9.8.31", "deploy/playbook_full_stack.yml", "deploy/hosts/vagrant_stage.yml"
    end
end
```